# How to return modified record in react-admin withLifecycleCallbacks hander

Tags: react-admin

The react-admin documentation includes guidance on [creating and using](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/withLifecycleCallbacks.html) these lifecycle callbacks.

But, the demonstrations only manipulate data in other kinds of resource.

The handler can modify the current record, such as generating a sequential counter of similar items loaded this year:

```
  afterCreate: async (
    record: CreateResult<Batch>,
    dataProvider: DataProvider
  ) => {
    try {
      const { data } = record
      const { id, yearOfReceipt: year } = data
      const yearVal: string = year
      const idVal: string = await generateBatchId(provider, year)
      const batchNumber = `V${idVal}/${yearVal}`
      await dataProvider.update<Batch>(R_BATCHES, {
        id,
        previousData: data,
        data: {
          batchNumber
        }
      })
      return record
    } catch (error) {
      return record
    }
  }
```

But, I think the method should return the modified record. So, it would return an modified version of the original record:

```
  afterCreate: async (
    record: CreateResult<Batch>,
    dataProvider: DataProvider
  ) => {
    try {
      const { data } = record
      const { id, yearOfReceipt: year } = data
      const yearVal: string = year
      const idVal: string = await generateBatchId(provider, year)
      const batchNumber = `V${idVal}/${yearVal}`
      const withBatchNumber = await dataProvider.update<Batch>(R_BATCHES, {
        id,
        previousData: data,
        data: {
          batchNumber
        }
      })
      // inject updated record
      return {...record, data: withBatchNumber}
    } catch (error) {
      return record
    }
  }
```

Will this break any `react-admin` logic?  Or is there a better way of implementing the above?

Note: we aren't modifying the record in the `beforeUpdate` logic, since we want to generate the counter after the new resource has successfully been saved.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be more correct and more reliable if the server did it.

Comment: The value returned by `create` will mostly only be used to populate cache data, but it will almost immediately be overridden by the result of the next `getList` or `getOne`. So as long as you persist the computed `batchNumber` in database, there should be no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have adopted the above practice, and in the month since then have not encountered any issues with returning the modified object.

This is probably because `react-admin` immediately retrieves a new copy of the element from the data-provider anyway - as @slax57 suggested